# Can't add Embree to my project, getting LNK1104 error

Tags: windows, cmake, embree

I'm trying to add Embree to an already working solution, following [this resource](https://www.embree.org/downloads.html) I've added to my `CMakeLists.txt` file the following:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(embree 3.0 REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${EMBREE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(application ${EMBREE_LIBRARY})
```

I've also created a Windows environment variable `embree_DIR` with my Embree installation folder ("C:\Program Files\Intel\Embree3 x64").

CMake configures the solution fine, but when I build I get a `fatal error LNK1104: impossible to open 'embree3.lib'`.

Just so you know, I actually have a `C:\Program Files\Intel\Embree3 x64\lib\embree3.lib` file.

Anyone has any clue why this might be happening?

Comment: If you add `message(${EMBREE_LIBRARY})` to the end of your CMake file, what does it print? Do this contain the *full* path to the library, or only the library name?

Comment: The full path actually

Answer (score 1):

Set `EMBREE_ROOT_DIR` e.g.:

```
set(EMBREE_ROOT_DIR "C:/thirdparty/vs2017/x64/embree-2.17.0")
```

Link to ${EMBREE_LIBRARIES}

```
target_link_libraries(YourApp
    ...
    ${EMBREE_LIBRARIES}
    ...
)
```